# JUnit test crashes in setUp

Tags: java, android, testing, junit, nullpointerexception

I'm testing two activities: the first one completes its tests and finishes, but the first test in the second one crashes with the following error:

```
Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NullPointerException''. Check device logcat for details
```

I figured the line `activity = getActivity();` in the test class gives a null and thus crashes the test. Here's the relevant part of the test class. Why does this happen, and how do I fix it?

```
public ResultActivityTest() {
    super(ResultActivity.class);
}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();

    activity = getActivity();
    displayoperands = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.result_textview);
    resultdisplay = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    canvas = (SurfaceView) activity.findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
    layoutRoot = (RelativeLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.rellay);
    back = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.back_button);

    activity.setImag1(2.0);
    activity.setImag2(2.0);
    activity.setReal1(2.0);
    activity.setReal2(2.0);
    activity.setOperation("A");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out after a bit of tampering with the activity and some trial and error. The problem was, the activity's onCreate demanded a bundle with variables from the calling activity. This being `null`, kept crashing the activity that the test tried to start without passing any variables. The solution is to initialise the required variables with a (dummy/default) value that works with the activity.